# How to unlock PayPal Test Account?

Tags: paypal, titanium, appcelerator, paypal-sandbox

We're working on an mobile app developed in Titanium Studio 3.2.0 and Titanium SDK 3.2.0.GA and Alloy 1.2.2 from Appcelerator. The app is being deployed to both Android (2.3.x and greater) and iOS(6.x or greater). To work with PayPal we're using the [Titanium's PayPal module](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/paypal).

When we started the payment test on Android we started to get the following message: *You PayPal account is restricted or locked. Go to www.paypal.com to resolve this issue:*

In iOS I'm getting the message: *An invalid parameter was sent: SENDER.*

I don't understand why my test account was locked, I tried to create a new test account and the same thing happened. It's weird because it used to work fine in iOS and suddenly after trying to test in Android now it's not working on both.

Here's the code I use:

```
function createPayPalButton()
{

    Titanium.Paypal = require('ti.paypal');

    var price = paypalPrice;

    var PaypalHolderView = Ti.UI.createView({
        width: "200dp",
        height : '50dp',
        top : '10dp',
        layout : 'horizontal',
        borderRadius : '5dp',
        backgroundColor : 'transparent'
    });

    var ppArgs = {
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
        height:"50dp",
        bottom:"20dp",
        textStyle: Titanium.Paypal.PAYPAL_TEXT_PAY, 
        appId:"APP-80W284485P519543T",
        buttonStyle: Ti.Paypal.BUTTON_194x37,
        paypalEnvironment: Ti.Paypal.PAYPAL_ENV_SANDBOX,
        feePaidByReceiver: false,
        transactionType: Ti.Paypal.PAYMENT_TYPE_DONATION,
        enableShipping: false,
        payment: {
            subtotal: price,
            tax: 0,
            shipping: 0,
            currency:"USD",
            recipient:"asama@x.com", // we're using a fake email, but we're not sure if this property should contain the email of the owner of the PayPal account.
            itemDescription:"Donation",
            merchantName:"OurMobileAppName" // not sure if we should reference to the package of our app i.e. to use com.mycompany.myapp or to just leave it as myapp
        }
    };

    var ppButton = Titanium.Paypal.createPaypalButton(ppArgs);

    PaypalHolderView.add(ppButton);

    $.MainContainer.add(PaypalHolderView);

    ppButton.addEventListener("paymentCancelled", function(e){
        Ti.API.info("Payment Canceled e: " + JSON.stringify(e));
    });

    ppButton.addEventListener("paymentSuccess", function(e){
        Ti.API.info('paymentSuccess e: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
        callback.success(e);
    });

    ppButton.addEventListener("paymentFailed", function(e){
        Ti.API.info('paymentFailed e: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
    });

    ppButton.addEventListener("paymentError", function(e){
        Ti.API.info("Payment Error e: " + JSON.stringify(e));
    });
}
```

Is this normal behaviour in Sandbox mode? Did I perform too many transactions? Can I unlock this test accounts?

Comment: What did PayPal's support say?

Comment: No word from them yet, but I have to get this to work fast since our release date is approaching and payments with PayPal are giving us a headache due to this problem, any ideas on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the PayPal support team didn't response back at all and we were left to find what was wrong.

What we discovered is that although our account for Production was activated to receive payments, the Sandbox account had to be activated separately, after doing that and updating our code for creating the PayPal button as follows:

```
var ppArgs = {
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height:"50dp",
    bottom:"20dp",
    appId:"APP-80W284485P519543T",
    textStyle: Titanium.Paypal.PAYPAL_TEXT_PAY, // Causes the button's text to change from "Pay" to "Donate"
    buttonStyle: Ti.Paypal.BUTTON_194x37,
    paypalEnvironment: Ti.Paypal.PAYPAL_ENV_SANDBOX,
    feePaidByReceiver: false,
    enableShipping: false,
    payment: {
        paymentType : Titanium.Paypal.PAYMENT_TYPE_SERVICE, // we added this
        subtotal: price,
        tax: 0,
        shipping: 0,
        currency:"USD",
        recipient:"your_recipient@fake.com"
    }
};
```

We were able to make test purchases after this.

Comment: I am having the same issue, where I am now trying to get the Live APID from paypal.  I have submitted the form and everytime I get a "MOre information Requested" message, and I don't even know what's missing.  Tried to call also, but no luck!  Do you have any suggestions on that?  Really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: We too received those messages, if I recall correctly you can answer directly or even ask for what were the issues and you must get a reply. Do not talk over the phone, I recommend sending emails to their developer support, they do answer although I don't know if the quality of service is the same everywhere.

 let' be honest here for a moment, PayPal guides aren't developer friendly, while we expect to be given as much information as possible the guide lack many details

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! Really appreciate it.  I just now emailed them and will see.  The other question I have for you is how did you manage to publish the application in the appstore?  From what I hear Apple won't let any applications through that are using 3rd party payment libraries, is this correct?

Comment: Well it depends, in our case we had to dump the idea (Android doesn't present this problem so more points to it).

You have to reach out Apple first and state how you want to use PayPal in your app and they'll tell you if it's ok or not. I recommend this doing first so you save yourself the time and energy in this.